# Update column with case

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I fix the second case `ELSE (LEFT JOIN)`? The first is going well.

```
UPDATE base_bw A 
SET A.Macro= 
CASE WHEN A.Cod1    IN ('213','233','236','239','272','287','296','299','311','314','330','346')
THEN 'Don't Change'
    ELSE 
    LEFT JOIN base_fix B 
    ON CONCAT(A.Parc, A.FCTA, A.DescTheme) = B.Local
    SET A.Macro = B.Macro 
END;
```

Comment: what is the problem? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableA A
JOIN tableB B
   ON CONCAT(A.Parc, A.FCTA, A.DescTheme) = B.Local   
SET A.Macro = B.Macro 
WHERE A.Cod1   NOT IN ('213','233','236','239','272','287','296','299',
                       '311','314','330','346')
```